# FInd array of words in String using regex

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to search some words in string , below is my code

```
$str="Chup Raho Episode 5 by Ary Digital 16th September 2014";

$keywords=array('Ary digital','geo');

echo in_string($keywords,$str,'all');
```

```
function in_string($words, $string, $option)
{
if ($option == "all") {
    $isFound = true;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $isFound = $isFound && (stripos($string, $value) !== false); // returns boolean false if nothing is found, not 0
        if (!$isFound) break; // if a word wasn't found, there is no need to continue
    }
} else {
    $isFound = false;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $isFound = $isFound || (stripos($string, $value) !== false);
        if ($isFound) break; // if a word was found, there is no need to continue
    }
}
return $isFound;
}
```

This function return true or false , if word found it return 1 and if not it return 0.I need to return word which i am searching ,because i want to do another search on this word in mysql.
Like if function found "Ary digital" then it should return "ary digital found".
Help required.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this (untested):

```
preg_match('#(word1|word2|word3)#',$string,$matches);
```

Then print_r($matches) to see the output of the matches array and grab the bit you want. From there you can return true/false etc.

Comment: if the array was just array('word1','word2','word3') (i.e. not a multi dimensional array) then just use preg_match('#('.implode('|',$array).')#',$string,$matches)

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite what you already have. Instead of returning a boolean push the matching keywords to a new array and return that one.

```
function in_string($keywords, $string, $searchAll = true) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        if (stripos($string, $keyword) !== false)
            array_push($matches, $keyword);
        if (!$searchAll)
            break;
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

By the way *regexes* are a lot slower (usually factor 10+) than this.

Comment: yes it works.Thanks.Just remove $ from stripos function